# Symfony API + AngularJS very slow response

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I have the following problem, I have API written in symfony 3, in angularJS I have written a front for this API and my problem is that the response time is very long, i.e. I am asking the API for a list of events which is 500, I am waiting for almost 30s to return them, I'm asking for a list of orders which is from 300 I am waiting 17s.

A backend in symfony is probably nothing to it, because even a postman asking for a list of events also takes 30s. The next thing is asking the API for the ticket code or it has been used up, the answer is only received after about 15s, which in the case of such a simple request is a tragic time.

I am seriously wondering what the problem is that this is how long it takes. On the other hand, in the situation of using Postman, the frontend also falls out because then it is not used at all.

I have no idea what the problem may be.

Comment: did you check e.g.: debugger?, sql queries? (lazy loading), serialization?

Comment: can you check the Network tab for a more detailed description of your delays? Are you sending 500 separate requests, or something?

Comment: I believe you are in the dev environment with a misconfigured system time that causes cache to be regenerated on every request. If you're in the dev environment, let me know and I can write up a more comprehensive answer.